# Can the main branch block merges for specific files while allowing changes in other files to be merged?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

For instance, consider two branches: A and B, with B branching off from A.

Currently, branch B has modifications in several files.
Additionally, there's a file C originating from branch A, which has also been modified.

When merging branch B back into branch A, is there an alternative approach to excluding only the changes in file C, rather than using .gitignore or cherry-pick?

In other words, I want C to proceed separately from A and B.

Thanks!

Comment: Is C a branch or a file now? Can you give a better example of your problem?

Comment: @poke C is a file like "C.txt". in branch A, C's content is "hello", while in B "hi". I want A's content "hello" to be maintained even after merging B into A. Is it possible to merge like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at this from the wrong perspective. Git is not about files, and it isn't the job of a branch to "block" anything. Git is about *commits*, and it is *your* job to construct a commit thoughtfully and intentionally.

So, the procedure for changing a file *C.txt* and having only those changes be merged into branch A is:

1. Make a branch from A.

   ```
   git switch A
   git switch -c B
   ```
2. Edit various files, including *C.txt*.

   ```
   # edit... edit...
   ```
3. Make a commit consisting *only* of *C.txt*:

   ```
   git add C.txt
   git commit -m 'modifications to C.txt only'
   ```
4. Merge B into A.

   ```
   git switch A
   git merge B
   ```

In other words, if you don't want the modifications to any other files to be merged into A, don't include those modification in the commit(s) that you merge into A.

Now, you might say: Okay, but I also want to "save" the changes to some other files — let's call them *X.txt* and *Y.txt* — that I made while I was working on branch B. (You might also say: I can't perform step 4, because if I switched to A, it would tromp on my modifications to other files in the working tree.)

Fine! Then you will have to have *another* branch that you do *not* merge into A (not yet, anyway). Let's go back to step 3:

3. Make a commit on B consisting *only* of *C.txt*:

   ```
   git add C.txt
   git commit -m 'modifications to C.txt only'
   ```
4. Make another branch and add everything to it:

   ```
   git switch -c B2
   git add .
   git commit -m 'modifications to everything'
   ```

Now, just as I said before, merge B into A — and throw B away. Switch back to B2, which is now your working branch, and make more modifications. If the same issue arises again, do the same thing again: add just *C.txt* to B2, add everything to another branch B3, and merge B2 into A.

This is *not the only way*. I'm just showing you the mindset. Your tools are *commits and branches* — and in a way they are the same tool, because a branch is nothing but a name for one commit.  So the point is, be nimble *with the tools you have*. It is amazing what you can do if you are willing to supply a little intentionality.

Comment: Though the answer may be not telling exactly about what I wanted to do, It is very fundamental answer that gives correct perspective. Thanks. I think I’m able to do what I wanted to do now.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by "not the only way... I'm just showing you the mindset". By the way, you might want to read my Git explanation: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/